# Vertx SSL/TLS Handshake failure while connecting solace server

Tags: vert.x, solace

I am using vert.x java client for connecting solace server. While using SSL certificates for connectivity, receiving below SSL handshake error.I am using settrustall(true) in my code. Could someone help with cause for the error and resolution.

Below is the error:
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bridge was not successfully started
    at io.vertx.amqpbridge.impl.AmqpBridgeImpl.createConsumer(AmqpBridgeImpl.java:174)
    at com.gtaa.nch.amqp.MyErrorResponse.lambda$2(MyErrorResponse.java:241)
    at io.vertx.amqpbridge.impl.AmqpBridgeImpl.lambda$startImpl$5(AmqpBridgeImpl.java:157)
    at io.vertx.proton.impl.ProtonClientImpl$ConnectCompletionHandler.handle(ProtonClientImpl.java:122)
    at io.vertx.proton.impl.ProtonClientImpl.lambda$connectNetClient$1(ProtonClientImpl.java:97)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetClientImpl.lambda$connect$2(NetClientImpl.java:113)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetClientImpl.doFailed(NetClientImpl.java:268)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetClientImpl.lambda$failed$12(NetClientImpl.java:264)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:337)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeFromIO(ContextImpl.java:195)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetClientImpl.failed(NetClientImpl.java:264)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetClientImpl.lambda$null$4(NetClientImpl.java:208)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:479)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:122)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.notifyHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1535)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1521)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1493)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handleUnwrapThrowable(SslHandler.java:1186)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1165)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1194)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:141)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Can you increase the logging of the TLS handshake, e.g. run your program with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake ? 
This should give you more detail on why the TLS handshake is failing to help determine the cause.

Answer (score 0):

This is in all likelihood an SSL configuration problem.

1. Check your bridge configuration targets the AMQP SSL port on the Solace broker, not the plain text port (defaults are 5671 rather than 5672)
2. Check the broker SSL configuration is valid (is the AMQP SSL service showing Operational UP?
3. Use sdkperf_jmsamqp to check that your SSL connection, certificates etc are valid.